# Setup an alert for multiple users in a sharepoint (2016) list via powershell?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, powershell

I was wondering if there is a way to setup multiple users with an alert on sharepoint (2016 on-prem)? I have researched to see how this is done via PowerShell but unfortunately I can only find ways to handle for a single user or multiple users on multiple lists etc.

Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Please follow the steps:**

1.Enable alerts for Web application

```
## To enable alerts for Web application
$SPwebapp=Get-SPWebApplication "http://SharePointSite.com"
$SPwebapp.AlertsEnabled = $true
$SPwebapp.Update()
 
# To Disable alerts for a Web application
$SPwebapp.AlertsEnabled = $false
$SPwebapp.Update()
```

2.Put multiple users into the same SharePoint group. (You can customize a SharePoint group in advance)

3.Please run the below PowerShell command to create an Alert for All users in a Group:

```
## Set alerts for all users in the SharePoint Group ##
$SPweb = Get-SPWeb "http://SharePointSite.com"
$SPgroup = $SPweb.Groups["SharePoint Owners"]
$SPlist = $SPweb.Lists["Shared Documents"]
foreach ($SPuser in $SPgroup.Users){
     $alert = $SPuser.Alerts.Add()
     $alert.Title = "My Alert"
     $alert.AlertType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAlertType]::List
     $alert.List = $SPlist
     $alert.DeliveryChannels = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAlertDeliveryChannels]::Email
     $alert.EventType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventType]::Add
     $alert.AlertFrequency = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAlertFrequency]::Immediate
     $alert.Update()
}
$SPweb.Dispose()
```

Comment: The script ran successfully but I do not see the names appear in the drop down of the site settings > User alerts section. I also ran a script to check that way as well but I still don't see the name I have listed within the sharepoint group. Will this still work if I use a sharepoint group created in AD? As this is what I used...Or does this need to be a SP group created within SharePoint?